# if empty field attribute required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a login form and I'd like to make the fields required so no empty fields get sended.

The problem is the password field, if I make it required, the javascript function will clear it and it won't get sended (the required msg will appear in the field).

The JS function creates another hidden field and puts there the hashed password, then the password field must be emptied (password.value = "";).

I'm thinking in using jquery attr() if is empty.

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    if (password.value = "") {
        password.attr("required", true);  // somehow this is not working...
    }

    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field.
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form.
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "password";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form.
    form.submit();
}
```

What can be the problem? Do I need to return or something?

What about other functions like register and change password? How do I simplify so much ifs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the form's onsubmit event handler instead of the onclick handler as the `required` flag doesn't stop the click event from being fired.

Then you should attach your event handler in the script instead of inline and...

1. Prevent the form from submitting
2. Then hash the password value.
3. Then resubmit the form

---

```
// Get the form element
var form = document.getElementById('login');

// Attach the submit event handler to the form element
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    // Stop initial submission event
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the password element
    var password = document.getElementById('password');

    // Update the password element's value with a hashed value
    password.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Resubmit the form   
    this.submit();
}
```

Comment: Well, all my javascripts are included using html in the head tags, so I'll need that window.onload handler. Thanks for you help! :)